# How to protect liquid assets from risk of hyperinflation

Tags: savings, investing, inflation, hyperinflation

I don't want to freeze my cash in any medium that would require me to look/wait for a buyer, wait for the collective investment fund to cash my shares as they take their allowance of time to cash them when they are cheapest, or risk the only office within 100km capable of turning my [specific asset] into cash is closed due to some local emergency.

I don't really care about turning profit on my savings, but I know better than leaving them on plain account in my country's native currency on percentage keeping up with current inflation - Hyperinflation has swallowed my long-term savings account once already, and the situation isn't really stable.

What asset is easy to liquefy (even in case of severe local crisis) but immune to local hyperinflation and strong against global crises, plus doesn't lose value over time, or at least loses it slower than cash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No asset is perfect or completely immune to losing value in times of crisis. With any investment your generally trading one type of risk for another.

Gold is often viewed as a safe haven asset as it has preserved its value in real terms through hundreds of years of history, but this leads to its market price often becoming overly speculative at times when people are worried about inflation which can cause its spot price to fluctuate wildly.

If you want something extremely liquid, you might want to consider a basket of foreign currencies which you view as more stable than your own.  Nothing is more liquid than cash, but the returns will be low and you'll be exposed to exchange rate risk.

Inflation linked securities from major governments will give you a return linked to that countries inflation index, but you can't be sure the measure used by that government will fully track the inflation you feel with your own lifestyle.  There's also the risk that in the opposite scenario of deflation these instruments will actually lose you money (in nominal terms).

Another consideration is to buy things with real tangible value, like real estate or commodities. Assets which humanity will always need like shelter and food are highly likely to retain value in a crisis - but soft commodities are hard to store and real estate is illiquid.

Do you see how every option comes with an equivalent risk?

Probably the best thing to do is take a few of these options and keep your portfolio well diversified. You can't ever know what type of crisis will come next and which assets will suffer until it happens - all you can do is make sure your risk is spread among different types of assets.

Comment: Nice discussion on the plusses and minuses of gold, and on the basket of foreign currencies. Great answer.

Comment: +1 agreed, nice answer. Asking - given that even 1/10 oz of gold is $170, is silver a good choice? It would seem to me 1oz silver rounds would be easier to negotiate.

Comment: +1 @Joe I believe you should have both, and I also consider 1/2oz silver rounds as well. Like any money - you get the large bills and you get the small change, not everyone can always break a $100 bill for you.

Comment: I love how doomsday preppers act like Gold will have some value in a post apocalyptic world. A bar of gold wouldn't be worth a sandwich in that world.

Comment: @JohnFx By that reasoning, neither will paper money or bank balances. The simple fact is that efficient trade pretty much requires some sort of generally-accepted medium of exchange. Currency serves that purpose quite well currently, but it is not the only thing that can fit the bill (no pun intended). *Also*, there's about a million gradients in "a post apocalyptic world". At once losing one's job and severe weather causing serious damage to one's dwelling without proper insurance would be devastating on the personal level, but barely noticeable to people outside of the immediate impact zone.

Comment: @JohnFx throughout pre-modern history, societies which developed markets for trade eventually invented money. Barter is inefficient and people naturally start to horde any material which doesn't degrade, is easily divisible and hard to counterfeit. Precious metals are surprisingly good at doing this. If I'm in a bunker and you want to buy some food from me, you'd better hope you coincidentally have something I need, the only other thing I would trust is Gold or Silver.

Comment: @Joe diversification is always good. Gold has a  special place in history and Silver has had a few nasty crashes when extra resources have suddenly appeared but I'd probably consider a basket of Gold, Silver, Platinum and maybe even more esoteric options like Palladium **if** there was a reasonably efficient way to buy and sell them in my location. I particularly like littleadv's comment about using Silver as smaller change for Gold as that's exactly what many societies used to do.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling very true, hyperinflation is not an apocalypse and may well be very localized. If I was in Zimbabwe I would have tried to put my money into USD, EUR, JPY, CHF, GBP etc and then buy foreign stocks.  Planning for an apocalypse is often overkill, as the Mayans will attest to.

Comment: @thepassiveinvestor The Mayan calendar didn't say anything more about the world ending at the turn of the 12th to 13th baktun, than the Gregorian calendar said anything about the world ending as the year 1999 turned into 2000.

Comment: @JohnFx - what's curious is the OP has stated he's lready gone through a cycle of hyperinflation. To you or e, this seems just that, a doomsday scenario, but there are many countries in he world, and inflation runs away now and then.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I am sure you're right, my comment was in jest.  Perhaps I should have said "as those who were convinced the Mayans had predicted one" will attest.